# Bash script works on manual running using sh -x , but not working in crontab

Tags: shell

Bash script works on manual running using `sh -x`, but not working in crontab. I have used correct command lines in crontab. When ran using `sh -x script.sh` it is giving proper output but when the script is placed in crontab it is not showing the output. Please help. The script has been provided below :

```
. $HOME/.profile
DIR=$HOME/scripts
export DIR
HOST=`hostname`
export HOST
mail=`cat $DIR/sample.lst`
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s "/ as system" << EOF
set feedback off;
set lines 1000;
set head off;
spool $DIR/sample.lst;
@$DIR/sample.sql;
spool off;
EOF
a=`ls -l $DIR/sample.lst | awk '{print $1}'`
if [ $a -ne 0 ]
then
sh $DIR/sample_1.sh
 mailx -s "$HOST :$ORACLE_SID : The output is " $mail < $DIR/sample.txt
fi
```

Comment: Can you add your crontab entry?

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps.

```
chmod 755 [SCRIPT.sh]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can  you try with this in your crontab?

Lets say you want to run the script every morning 0700HRS.

```
00 07 * * * bash ; cd $HOME/scripts ; ./script.sh 1>out_script 2>&1
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.